# Batch convert pdfs to Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, automation

I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this question but I'm getting a bit desperate. I have 300 pdfs that I need to take bits from and combine into a single Excel file. The PDFs are not selectable, just images. If there's a way I can automate the process, that would be great, but what I am really looking for is a more flexible version of Mechanical Turk. Any ideas would be very very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Convert them into raster images with imagemagick and apply some OCR tool on them.

Comment: 300 pdf images = one heavy excel file